# My Hard Drive Hates Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, external-hard-drive, smart

Recently I was using my external NTFS-formatted 3TB HDD on my Linux OS again, as I always do. Nothing out of the ordinary.
At some random point I received an Input/Output error when trying to access files. I tried to do other things on the drive, checked more files and it was really slow and it felt like I was dealing with the last living hours of my almost dead hard drive. Therefore I started to rsync my newest changes to the backup drive. Sadly I had to restart the computer at some point which led me to rsyncing once again, but this time it got stuck on a certain folder on the drive which gave Input/Output error again as the output of rsync's error log. I reran rsync more and more and it always got stuck on this folder.
Before I tried to rsync, after I realized something is wrong with the drive I wanted to smartctl it, but it always failed with

`Read Device Identity failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.`

which gave me even more the impression that something was **seriously** wrong with my HDD. Again, smartctl (with different arguments each time) didn't work for me, at all and it seemed like my HDD is still barely breathing and I wondering about what to do next before it completely dies off. (Note: SMART worked in the past 100%. It is also enabled in BIOS.)

Now that happened all on LINUX. On a Debian testing based derivative, to be more precise.

So let us change to Window's view now:
At some point in the middle of the aforementioned sequence of events I changed to Windows again and ran a CHKDSK, which repaired a couple of errors. Re-running this didn't find any new errors. Also a couple of months ago before this happened I knew that this HDD received exactly 600 uncorrectable sectors. I monitored them and it always stayed at exactly this number.

Now what did Windows say after all that happened?
I rebooted into Windows to check if at least Crystal Disk Info works or if one of the NTFS-native Windows tools could help me out better.
Oh wonder, Crystal Disk Info actually worked. Without even taking long or anything like that. And even more astounding: the only thing wrong with my hard drive was **still** the exact same amount of 600 uncorrectable sectors. I was expecting some dead piece of metal being in the deep reds of SMART-ville while gaining hundreds of new uncorrectable sectors each minute.
But that didn't happen.

In fact on Windows (almost) everything went fine. The HDD wasn't slow. I could do file operations with it, as usual, etc. The only problem that actually migrated (partially) is the folder from earlier that gave an Input/Output error when trying to rsync. I couldn't even manually delete or move it when in Linux. But hero Windows 10 saved the day by letting me actually delete this whole folder after archiving it. It took a while, but it worked.

So here are my questions:

- What could the possible reasons be for this to happen?
- Why is Linux telling me that the hard drive is so broken that I can't even SMART it while a Windows program can?
- Why is the hard drive very slow and annoying when booted into Linux but working pretty fine on Windows?

I want to understand this...

Comment: My experience has been that Linux and Windows don't always play well together on the same partition. Sorry, this is not an answer, and I do not know which (or perhaps both) causes an issue, though Windows can destroy a grub  boot and Linux, if not careful can mess up hiberfil.sys, causing problems on Windows boot..

Comment: IMHO what happened is that you had a structure error in the NTFS filesystem ("**It took a while, but it worked.**") to which the "official" NTFS is more resilient than the Linux one which is reverse-engineered. It is also possible that the [Linux NTFS has some different code for partitions >2TB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Scalability) and this code may be somewhat less tested.

Comment: Does it mean that, theoretically, if I would completely reformat the drive after writing a new partition table it may help or "fix" it a little?

Comment: If you format it for a Linux FS yes :) But if you want to keep NTFS, splitting it in two NTFS partitions <2TB could help.

Comment: Any Linux FS or a specific one?

Comment: Does said hdd have 4k sectors. and need to be aligned to 4k?  Linux version? Kernel version?  Did you try MBR or use GPT?  (You need GPT)

Comment: I already made clear which Linux version, etc. is used. I didn't check the alignment. Also the disk doesn't *need* GPT. MBR works but wouldn't use the whole space. Anyway, of course it is GPT formatted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution was solved by deleting and recreating the partitions on the disk.

Comment: @Ramhound So according to you, where wouldn't it be off-topic? Is it even off-topic on a forum dedicated to discuss Computer related things in general? This voting as "off-topic" is getting way overboard on the stackexchange sites, lately... Not everything is "off-topic" just because it isn't a picture book example of a problem that is showed as an example in the tutorial tour.

Comment: @Akito - You are taking the close vote way to personal.  I am trying to protect the quality of this question, and trying to avoid, bad answers from being submitted in the future with the close vote.  But go ahead, take it personal, and talk down to me with statements like you made.

Answer (score 0):

I moved everything from this hard drive to another one with a little struggle. After making sure that everything was backed up I deleted this drive's only partition in Windows' Disk Management. Afterwards I started PowerShell, initiated diskpart, selected the correct disk, issued the `clean all` command, which overwrote the whole drive from A-Z.
Luckily after the clean-up finished even **all** the pending and uncorrectable sectors disappeared. After 2 days of watching and checking S.M.A.R.T. they didn't reappear, yet.